# Как сделать рамку для RadioButton отдельным фреймом Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton, frame

Нужно сделать отдельный фрейм и задать ему параметр bg, так сказать покрасить какую то часть экрана, а потом на этом покрашенном фоне создать выборку(RadioButton). У меня получился такой код, но он не работает:

```
frm = Frame(root, bg="#cc33ee", width=340, height=400)
rv = IntVar()
rbtn = RadioButton(frm, text="Test",variable=rv, value=0)
rbtn.pack()
frm.pack()
```

Насколько я понял фрейм меняет свой размер под кнопочку, розовый цвет за кнопкой совсем немного виден, может кто показать в чем проблема?

Comment: Рамка и для RadioButton - это и так отдельный фрейм. Если вам нужно задать размер фрейма, чтобы был виден фоновый цвет, то об этом и пишите.

Comment: @insolor, но если добавить еще одну радиокнопку меньшего размера по тексту, то станет видно фрейм который красили, но вопрос почему фрейм становится такого размера, подходящего только под все элементы, но никак не тот размер который задан при создании обьекта

Comment: Потому что pack так работает. Если нужно чтобы размещалось с фиксированным размером, используйте place.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы фрейм показался из-под кнопки - добавьте её отступы:

```
rbtn.pack(padx=10, pady=4)
```

[image: -]

Дополнительно фрейм можно заставить заполнить родительский виджет:

```
frm.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

[image: -]